# Interface usage on controller implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop, interface

I'm using `MVC` pattern in my application. For each model class I have a controller one. All controller classes have a `saveOrUpdate()` method. I am wondering if this is enough to create an **Interface** which defines said method, and then all controller implements it.

Please note that `saveOrUpdate()` receive a model class as a parameter. So it would be something like `UserController#saveOrUpdate(User user)`,  `CourseController#saveOrUpdate(Course course)`, `AppleManager#saveOrUpdate(Apple apple)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is generic repository which implements generic functionality for a given entity. I've recently started implementing [Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) along with [Unit of Work](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/581487/Unit-of-Work-Design-Pattern) in my MVC projects. Here is how I do that.

MyDbContext.cs:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection”)
        {
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    }
```

Unit of Work:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        //private variable for db context
        private MyDbContext _context;
        //initial db context variable when Unit of Work is constructed
        public UnitOfWork()
        {
            _context = new MyDbContext();
        }
        //property to get db context
        public MyDbContext Context
        {
            //if not null return current instance of db context else return new
            get { return _context ?? (_context = new MyDbContext()); }
        }
        //save function to save changes using UnitOfWork
        public void Save()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Generic Repository:

```
public class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
    {
        protected readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbSet;

        public RepositoryBase(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _dbSet = _unitOfWork.Context.Set<T>();
        }

    public virtual void Save()
        {
            _unitOfWork.Save();
        }

        public virtual void Add(T entity)
        {
            _dbSet.Add(entity);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
        }
    //Similarly you can have Update(), Delete(), GetAll() implementation here

    }
```

Entity Repository inheriting from generic repo:

```
public class UserRepository:RepositoryBase<User>,IUserRepository
    {
        public UserRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork)
        {
        }
    //Here you can also define functions specific to User
    }
```

Controller:

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUserRepository _dbUserRepository;

        public UserController(IUserRepository dbUserRepository)
        {
            _dbUserRepository = dbUserRepository;
        }

        // GET: /User/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
        var users = _dbUserRepository.GetAll();

            return View(users.ToList());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create an interface

```
interface ISave
 {
      void Save(object obj);
 }
```

now in your controller implement it.

```
public class AppleControler : Controller , ISave
{

        public void Save(Object obj) 
        {
              //you can cast your object here. 

        }

 }
```

Option two

```
 interface ISave<T>
 {
      void Save(T obj);
 }


public class AppleControler : Controller , ISave<Apple>
{

        public void Save(Apple obj) 
        {

        }

 }
```